# dcevm hotswap agent openjdk amazon corretto

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, dcevm, corretto

What is compatible DCEVM jdk version with amazon corretto? We are trying to setup hotswap agnt for faster hybris development.
We tried on openjdk that works but since we are using amazon corretto 8 we need compatible DCEVM JDK.